# Is the source code for svctraceviewer available

Tags: wcf, svctraceviewer

I would like to customize the svctraceviewer but do not want to start from scratch. Does any one know of a custom implementation or if the source code is available ?

Comment: You can use Reflector with some plugin to export code to files.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka I successfully tried to dissassemble the application but the result was messy and hard to reuse..

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not available. The same goes for the WCF Test client (and rest of the tools).

A couple of years ago, I did a small proof of concept/hack to show that it was possible to "inject" two extra menu items into the test client to save/load test parameters. See
http://www.larswilhelmsen.com/2008/10/04/wcf-test-client-extended/